# Check the version of an application?

Tags: java, android, xml

I use a code like this to check for a file

```
        File file = new File("/system/app/xxx.apk");
```

If I want to know the version of this apk, how do I?

Comment: Is it your application that you want to check?

Answer (score 0):

Use this to get the apk version:

```
PackageInfo pInfo = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0);
version = pInfo.versionName;
```

or

```
String versionName = context.getPackageManager()
    .getPackageInfo(context.getPackageName(), 0).versionName;
```

Comment: But I do not want to know the version of my application, but the application that I want in system/app.

Answer (score 0):

Version will be present in your manifest file.If this is not your answer please put more details in question

Answer (score 0):

```
PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
String apkPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "xxxx.apk";
PackageInfo pi = pm.getPackageArchiveInfo(apkPath, 0);

String versionName = pi.versionName; 
int versionCode = pi.versionCode;
```

My code assumes the apk is stored in the root directory of storage, so you need to replace `apkPath` with the path to your apk.